# How to extract conventional standard type CIF files from Materials Project through pymatgen or matminer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-mining, pymatgen

I use Matminer to get CIF file from Materials Project.The code is:

```
from matminer.data_retrieval.retrieve_MP import MPDataRetrieval  
mpdr = MPDataRetrieval(api_key='My_key')  
df = mpdr.get_dataframe(criteria='Mg2SiO4', properties=['cif'])
```

The CIF file I extracted from the above code is displayed on the webpage of the MP database as 'Cumputed'. Its structure in VESTA is shown in the following figure
[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVegX.png)[figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0z9l.png)

But I see that this is a 'Conventional Standard' type CIF file on the MP database website. What I want to extract is this type of CIF file
[figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GoBO.png)[figure 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6883Q.png)

So I wonder if there is a way to directly extract 'Conventional Standard' type CIF files, either with Matminer or with Pymatgen.Or is there any way to convert a CIF file of type 'Cumputed' into a CIF file of type 'Conventional Standard'.